# Changing the upload path of a specific file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I want every time I upload a PDF file to my site, instead of the default WordPress path, my file will be saved in a different path.

For this purpose, I have placed the following filter in the `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_upload_directory( $file ) {
    // Check if the file is a PDF
    if ( $file['type'] == 'application/pdf' ) {
        // Set the upload directory to a custom location
         $file['url'] = '/wp-content/uploads/test-for-pdf/' . $file['name'];
        $file['error'] = false;
    }
 
    return $file;
}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```

By placing this filter, the PDF file is uploaded correctly in WordPress, but it is saved in its default path and no file is uploaded in the path I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, although I haven't tested it.

```
function custom_upload_directory( $file ) {
    // Check if the file is a PDF
    if ( $file['type'] == 'application/pdf' ) {
        // Set the upload directory to a custom location
         add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'pdf_upload_dir' );
    }
 
    return $file;
}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_directory' );

function pdf_upload_dir($param){
    $mydir = '/test-for-pdf';
    $param['path'] = $param['basedir'] . $mydir;
    $param['url']  = $param['baseurl'] . $mydir;
    remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'pdf_upload_dir' );
    return $param;
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked correctly. Thank you very much for your time and this very good code that you wrote for me.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the wp_handle_upload_prefilter page on WP (which I don't use) you don't get the option to change the path in that filter, only the name.

The default location is **defined** during bootstrap, and I'd advise not screwing with it. Instead use a plugin, or write a cron script to move the files.

See: https://devowl.io/knowledge-base/real-physical-media-change-wp-content-uploads-folder/

Comment: I don't want to change the path of all the files I upload. Only a special file like PDF should be uploaded separately from all other files and forever only in the same path.